# How to keep list of connections RxJS

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, rxjs

I want to montitor active chrome runtime connections using RxJS, the following works but there must be a cleaner way of doing it.

```js
import { Subject, merge } from "rxjs";
import { scan, map } from "rxjs/operators";

type Port = chrome.runtime.Port;

const onConnect$ = new Subject<Port>();
const onDisconnect$ = new Subject<Port>();

onConnect$.subscribe(port => port.onDisconnect.addListener(port => onDisconnect$.next(port)));

const connectedPorts$ = merge(
  onConnect$.pipe(map(port => ({ type: "connected", port }))),
  onDisconnect$.pipe(map(port => ({ type: "disconnected", port })))
).pipe(
  scan((connections, action) => {
    if (action.type == "connected") return [...connections, action.port];

    return connections.filter(c => c.sender?.id != action.port.sender?.id);
  }, [] as Port[])
);

connectedPorts$.subscribe(conns => console.log("Connected Ports Updated", conns));
```

Comment: What part of this implementation don't you find "clean" specifically? I don't know much about the Chrome extension API, but it looks like you might have a leak? (i.e. `port.onDisconnect.addListener` doesn't look like it has a mirroring remove listener call. If so, you could probably use [`fromEventPattern`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEventPattern) to set up this source to avoid manually creating subjects and subscribing them.)

Comment: @miqh well im thinking that I should need the intermediary "action" mapping for the "connectedPorts$", im assuming there is a better operator or something I can use here but im not sure how to google for it :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Haven't tested this myself, but it looks to be consistent with the Chrome runtime API.)

One way in which your current approach could be cleaner is to better generalize the creation of runtime event streams. Using Subjects (as well as subscribing to listeners within another call to subscribe) contributes to complexity, and usually unnecessarily.

This code sets up two instances of `Observable<Port>`, one of just-connected ports, and one of just-disconnected ports.

```
const fromRuntimeEvent = (target, eventType) =>
  new Observable((observer) => {
    const listener = (event) => observer.next(event);
    try {
      target[eventType].addListener(listener);
    } catch (e) {
      observer.error(e);
    }
    return () => target[eventType].removeListener(listener);
  });

const connections$ = fromRuntimeEvent(chrome.runtime, 'onConnect');
const disconnectsFor = (port) => fromRuntimeEvent(port, 'onDisconnect');

const disconnections$ = connections$.pipe(
  mergeMap((port) => disconnectsFor(port))
);
```

From here, using `scan` as you already are makes sense to me, just be sure to account for disconnects as well.

Comment: this is not strictly the answer I was looking for (was hoping to clear up the scan) but its definately useful so im going to give it the answer anyways for now. Thanks!